# Catch signals in Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, signals, flask

I'm busy writing a RESTful API in flask using flask views to drive the API. Since the application is sizable, I'm modularizing the code into blueprints. I've run into some trouble when trying to catch signals in a blueprint. I can happily write the 'connect signal' code in my main `__init__.py` file but I'd like to write the signal listeners in the relevant blueprint so as not to have the main `create_app` method cluttered with blueprint specific code.

Currently I have this [simplified] working code:

```
def create_app(debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)
    @mysignal.connect_via(app)
    def print_howdy(sender, **extra):
       print "howdy"
```

I'd like to move the signal connection code into my_blueprint, but cannot find a way to do that elegantly. How can I make this work?

Comment: Does `connect_via(current_app)` work?

Comment: Alas, it doesn't. I think it's because the method is never called.

Comment: So the real question is why doesn't `current_app` let you register listeners? It works for hooks like `before_request`.

Comment: Looks like `Signal.connect` works but `Signal.connect_via` doesn't. The former doesn't let you specify which sender you're listening to, but you can filter that within the listener or create a wrapper that does it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the decorator syntax in Python is sugar:

```
@decorator
def decorated():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def decorated():
    pass

decorated = decorator(decorated)
```

Therefore, you can define `print_howdy` in your blueprint and import it along with your blueprint.  In order to keep things clean, you can even have a list of signal listeners defined in your blueprint and import them all in one go:

```
mysignal.connect_via(app)(print_howdy)
```

or even:

```
# blueprint.py
def print_howdy(): pass
def print_seeya(): pass

MYSIGNAL_LISTENERS = (print_howdy, print_seeya)

# __init__.py
from blueprint import MYSIGNAL_LISTENERS
for listener in MYSIGNAL_LISTENERS:
    mysignal.connect_via(app)(listener)
```

You can even abstract this pattern into a function:

```
from werkzeug.utils import import_string

DEFAULT_SIGNALS = ('MYSIGNAL', 'MYOTHERSIGNAL')

def register_blueprint_and_signals(app, bp_path, signals=DEFAULT_SIGNALS):
    bp = import_string(bp_path)
    app.register_blueprint(bp)


    signal_path = bp_path.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + "."
    for signal in signals:
        try:
            listeners = import_string(signal_path + signal + '_LISTENERS')
        except ImportError:
            continue

        for listener in listeners:
            signal.connect_via(app)(listener)
```

Which you could then use like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
register_blueprint_and_signals(app, "my_module.my_blueprint")
register_blueprint_and_signals(app, "another.blueprint", ['ANOTHERSIGNAL'])
```

Comment: You're suggesting that I import the blueprint as well as the function stored in the same file as the blueprint. Ideally I'd like to avoid a separate import since that would require me to change __init__.py every time I add a connector. Can I not somehow load the connectors as the blueprint gets registered?

Comment: @Gevious - I've updated my answer with an example of how you might load the connectors with the blueprint - let me know if anything isn't clear!

Comment: Thanks. I like the solution of changing the blueprint loader. The function mostly worked, except that 'signal' in the final line is a string not a function. I used import_string to import the actual signal based on the string and it all worked nicely